# Passing argument into shell script as a form of txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to know how to access the contents of a variety of txt files by passing arguments into shell scripts. I'll have different files and I'm expecting to execute with this command:

```
./script.sh FileA.txt
```

What should I put into my shell script so that I can access and manipulate the contents of the files?

I tried this but it outputs 0:

```
echo "$#"
```

I also tried these, but both output nothing:

```
for i in $1
do
     echo "$i"
done
```

```
echo "$1"
```

Comment: Sorry, I should’ve made that clear

Comment: Please post your entire script and show how you're running it. The results you're getting imply that you're either calling the script wrong or you aren't accurately showing us what it's in it. Based on your description `echo "$#"` and `echo "$1"` should print `1` and `FileA.txt`, respectively.

Comment: `$i` is just the name of the file. Use `cat "$i"` to show the contents of the file.

Comment: And if you want to loop over all the arguments, use `for i in "$@"`

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the contents see this link to understand bash arguments more https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-command-arguments/ . Also as @Barmar said, to iterate through a list of arguments of unknown quantity use `for i in "$@"` .

edit
and as @Barmar said, $1 is simply the name of the argument. So echoing $1 will just echo the name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question fully. Lets assume you have list of file names in a text file "FileA.txt". 
And you wanted to run some commands for each file in the "FileA.txt" file.

Can you try below:

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
  echo $i
done
```